# How to show different Message for different input length in EditText?

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements

I want to show some different message to user for different length of input they make. But my code is not working. What's wrong with that?

```
EditText boxID = findViewById(R.id.vcInput);
Button button = findViewById(R.id.refresh);
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.message)

final int inputLength = boxID.getText().toString().length();


if(inputLength >= 10 && inputLength <= 11)
  {tv.setText("Refresh request sent");}

else if(inputLength<1)
       {tv.setText("VC number field looks empty");} //Only this one works at any input length

else if(inputLength>1 && inputLength<10)
       {tv.setText("VC number must be at least 10 digit");}

else {tv.setText("Wrong input");}
```

[image: Screenshot of my code]

Comment: How is it not working specifically?

Comment: You need a `addTextChangedListener`

Comment: Only the 1st Else if message (VC number field looks empty) shows at any length of input..

Comment: Remove toString(); 
final int inputLength = boxID.getText().length();

Comment: Yes, I put OnClickListener, here just shortened the code to the fact I was facing.

Comment: Please edit your code and add the listener: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: MBW, I used OnClickListener as usual, I was working fine with single condition in if(), but when I put 2 condition added by &&, then it stopped working.

Comment: Vivek Makwana, I tried now removing toString(). Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for, is probably [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher)

Example use:

```
boxID.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        int inputLength = s.length();


        if(inputLength >= 10 && inputLength <= 11)
          {tv.setText("Refresh request sent");}

        else if(inputLength<1)
          {tv.setText("VC number field looks empty");} 

        else if(inputLength>1 && inputLength<10)
          {tv.setText("VC number must be at least 10 digit");}

        else {tv.setText("Wrong input");}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `inputLength` was `final`. Initially the inputLength was empty and it was saved into the final field `inputLength` with value 0. That's why only 2nd condition is triggering.

The `inputLength` value was set before `onClick` was triggered.

A solution is either use `TextWatcher` or a simpler one is just move `inputLength` inside `onClick`, in this way you can get a new value for inputLength every `onClick` trigger :

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int inputLength = boxID.getText().toString().length();


       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
          @Override
          public void run() {
             if(inputLength >= 10 && inputLength <= 11)
                tv.setText("Refresh request sent");

             else if(inputLength<1)
                tv.setText("VC number field looks empty"); //Only this one works at any input length

             else if(inputLength>1 && inputLength<10)
                tv.setText("VC number must be at least 10 digit");

             else tv.setText("Wrong input");
          }
       })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have 3 conditions (actually 4)
 `inputLength >= 10 && inputLength <= 11`
`inputLength<1`
`inputLength>1 && inputLength<10`
and `else`

You can make it like this:

```
if(inputLength >= 10 && inputLength <= 11)
  {tv.setText("Refresh request sent");}

if(inputLength<1)
       {tv.setText("VC number field looks empty");}

if(inputLength>1 && inputLength<10)
       {tv.setText("VC number must be at least 10 digit");}

if(inputLength > 11)
   {tv.setText("Wrong input");}
```

I've had similar problems with `else if` statement. I had to rebuild my conditions tree.